# ASP.NET MVC 5: How to (re)sign/update the identity/cookie of users after updating their claims?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

I've implemented **ASP.NET Claims-based security**. Any administrator can edit the claims of all users. What I'm trying to achieve is that whenever a user is edited the claims of this user should immediately be updated - without forcing that user to logout and login again (so his cookie gets updated).

`ApplicationSignInManager.SignIn` seems to be the right choice to (re)sign the identity of a user and this already works as long as I edit the claims of the current user (edit "myself"). **But how to (re)sign/update the identity/cookie of other users?**

Comment: I think it's not possible to update other user cookie. But you can force every request to hit database for authorization so users cookie will be update per request.Take a look at this

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't like the approach to set the cookie/identity interval to 0. As you say the database gets hit every single request and that is not what I want. Currently I use a static list 'InvalidUsers' and every user checks himself every request if he's in that list. If so they must be resigned. It works but I think there must be a better solution.